# "Selection to cursor" not working in blender

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, selection-tools, 3d-cursor

[image]

This is how my blender model looks like.
I have inserted an uvsphere and a curve and i wanted to attach that curve path to  particular point of sphere.

I changed the center of curve path  to the end (set origin to 3d cursor) and changed the point from center to the desired point in uvsphere and tried to parent both with Ctrl P and i was successful doing this as you can see in the image but when i want to move that curve path to that parent uvsphere using selection to cursor option:

Nothing is actually happening.
That curve path is supposed to move to that point as i followed a tutorial, but it is not.
I have been using the latest version of blender, I'm not sure what exactly is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the curve/path to mesh first and **then** use this option as it 100% works with meshes.

And if you need a curve/path, select a vertex on the sphere, extrude it to shape, select the shape and convert the selection to curve. I use it when I i.a. need bevel objects that are not round.